# How to deal with file paths in Flask

Tags: python, flask

I'm sure this has been already asked but there are so many hits with "path" and "Flask" in them that are not quite what I'm looking for.

I have something like

```
root/
 app.py
 dev/
   notebook.ipynb
 models/
   model.pb
 core_module/
   preprocessing.py
   east.py
 app_module/
   infer_code.py
```

In `preprocessing.py` I have:

```
from .east import TextDetector
text_detector = TextDetector('../models/frozen_east_text_detection.pb')
```

In `notebook.ipynb` I have:

```
from core_module.preprocessing import *
```

This works fine!

Now, in `app.py` I have the standard boilerplate for a Flask app and

```
from app_module.infer_code import infer_code
```

and in `infer_code.py` I have:

```
from core_module.preprocessing import *
```

So `infer_code.py` has the same import line as `notebook.ipynb`.

BUT, when I run `python app.py` I get a not found error for `model.pb`. The only way I can fix it is by going into `preprocessing.py` and changing the file path to `'models/frozen_east_text_detection.pb'`.

So how can I keep using `notebook.ipynb` for development purposes, while also being able to run the flask app, without having to toggle the path in `preprocessing.py`?

Answer (score 0):

cd into the app folder to make it app's root dir

then follow all the paths from there

e.g: /dev/notebook.ipynb

will open the file **notebook.ipynb** if called from app